# PHP script, select on server 1 and insert on server 2 if iD doesn't exist (i.e. new records)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

We have a phone system database on one server that we cloned/dumped to our local server, but now we need to keep our version updated. Obviously, tables and schema are the same, I just want to run this scheduled script to update with new records that don't exist on the local table (i.e. records that were created since last update).

Below is a test select/insert block. The select query worked on it's own originally, but now I've modified it to use a loop with hopes of using numrows and a foreach to capture everything in the select.

The session table has about 35 columns so I'm looking for the best way to go about this without having to declare every column. I originally tried to do this using update on duplicate key or insert/ignore using a `not exists` but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Basically, once I select everything, if my table on server 2 doesn't contain a record with the SESSIONID primary key, I want to insert it. I just need some assistance creating this loop script.

Example:

if the table on server 1 has 2 rows with sessionID 12345, and 12346, but my table on server 2 only has up to sessionID 12344, I want to insert the whole records for those two IDs.

```
//Defining credentials
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$servername2 = "";
$username2 = "";
$password2 = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// Check connection2
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";


//Query to select * from Session table on server 1
$query1 = "select * from cdrdb.session";
$results = mysqli_query($conn1, $query1);

foreach ($results as $r => $result) {
  $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "insert into ambition.session a where not 
exists(a.SESSIONID)");
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend setting your second server to a `slave` and let mysql take care of all of this.

Comment: We attempted this with no success, and the server 1 database is read only so I've been tasked with a solution so that we can have all of the data updated on our local server. This was the route that was decided upon, I just don't know the best way to finish the loop. All I should need is a way to declare the SESSIONID primary key of each table as a variable to be used on the loop and use numrows to check if there are results where the id exists on S1 but not S2

Comment: Please explain in detail what is wrong with the script you have (current behavior/error messages vs expected outcome). Without context it could be anything from a syntax error to incorrect behavior, and we wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: @GolezTrol there are no errors yet because it's not complete. I'm just not sure how to complete it. You can see my select query, and then my foreach taking those elements into account. But my insert is incorrect using ```where not exists``` but it gets my point across. I need to modify that to insert properly, saying if ```sessionid``` from my select is not in my table on server 2, then insert. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense as a story, but it's unclear what the actual *question* is. You seem to have quite clear what to do. Just google the syntax and do it. I'm a bit confused on what you need of us.

Comment: Well everything I've found is more for inserting certain values based on arrays, but I specifically want to insert each record, all 35 columns, but only if they're new (i.e. the SESSIONID doesn't exist in the newer table). I just can't figure out how to modify the foreach loop. If I were to create a variable based on SESSIONID, where would I apply that variable. I'm just unclear on the exact format to use

Comment: @GolezTrol or what if I did this ```$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cdrdb.session");



$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "insert ignore into ambition.session");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));```  Then how would I use the php syntax to insert all? My select pulled 35 columns, so would I need to do Values(?,?,?) with 35 checkmarks?

Comment: Yes, why not? With a simple array an some loops you can do that easily. You don't need to copy a chunk of code 35 times..